# GCP cannot login to serial port root account because of NOFAIL_OPTION in etc/fstab

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

[image]

Long story short, I was mounting a disk to my vm instances but I didn't specify the NOFAIL_OPTION on /etc/fstab. Thus, after resarting the instance, i could not access the ssh. After trying to access the serial console, I got the error in the image above. I have tried to search some answer and have add startup script to add sudo user
[image]

However, it didn't solve my problem. Basically,I need the data on the boot and additional persistent disk. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You have messed up the boot process. You will need to mount the disk on another VM and repair by hand. Search Stackoverflow for example answers.

Comment: Could you please link me to that? I tried this approach but still figuring out how to mount the existing boot disk to new VM

Comment: There was a similar question in the last couple of days. Examples and articles are fairly easy to find. I wrote an article on how to recover from a UFW lockout. Read method 2 in this article: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! Yes, I think there are some people like me that is not too familiar in managing cloud server/instance. Now i just realized many articles provide the solution that might work but actually frame it as another problem. Maybe it just didn't come to mind when people is troubleshooting a spesific problem or maybe the articles should be framed as a more general problem. However, the method from your link works for me to make changes to the disk. Thankyou very much pal !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the problem by making changes to the file by attaching the bootable disk as additional disk on new instance just like John said in his [article](https://jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout)
:) Thanks! hope this will be helpful for those who could not access ssh and need to make changes to the unbootable system file.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me recently. I solved the issue by attaching the boot disk of the problematic instance to a new instance, however, the NO_FAIL causing the system to break is what interests me. This has never happened before. The UUID is correct, and the syntax is also correct, hence what was the cause of the original problem in your case? I'm still trying to figure mine out.

Comment: In my case, I was careless when editing the file in which i copy-pasted "NOFAIL_OPTION" instead of "nofail" or "nobootwait" as the value